# Should my 12 month old get milk in addition to nursing?

Tags: toddler, breastfeeding, milk

I'm still nursing my 12 1/2 month old, about 2-3 times a day. I also give him some cow's milk in his cereal in the morning. Should he be getting any cow's milk in addition to this?

To clarify, I've seen a suggestion of about 16 oz of milk a day for a baby this age, and I was wondering if that was in addition to, or in place of, nursing?

Comment: Most babies (and people for that matter) for most of history did not drink cow's milk or the milk of any other non-human creature for that matter.  Drinking milk is weird.

Answer (score 2):

Is there something, specifically, that you're concerned about?

Breastmilk and cow's milk taste about as similar as coffee and Pepsi. So baby won't be looking for cow's milk thinking it's yours.

Nutrition-wise, as long as baby is getting all of the nutrition he needs and can physically chew (if necessary) and swallow, he can eat/drink just about anything. Things like milk are actually a good way to get baby extra calories if he's behind on his growth curve, because it's pretty calorie and nutrient dense, without being hugely filling. This can be something to watch out for, but it's on par with any other foods and keeping everything in moderation, while watching your child's cues.

The main thing that you might have to watch out for is lactose intolerance. However, if you've been consuming dairy products while pregnant and/or breastfeeding and it hasn't caused problems, it's not likely to cause problems with him consuming it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're planning to start weaning him now, then yes. But I didn't think kids who breastfeed got supplements of dairy. (We only bottle-fed our little ones, and ISTR that we started weaning them around one year.)